# Transferring certain colored cells to other excel sheets

Tags: excel, data-transfer

I was wondering if it is possible to transfer certain colored cells to other excel sheets. I have colored the approved cells green and the non approved cells red. There are two different spreadsheets I want distribute this data to, one is called the approved sheet and the other is called the non approved sheet. The reason I would like to make this automatic because there are around 80k rows of data and doing that manually would take forever.

Thank you for the help and all the information provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind doing two copy/pasting, you can insert a filter

[image]

then filter on the specific colours. After that, copy the relevant cells and paste into the required sheet.

[image]

And then repeat for the other colour.

Comment: So if I went through these steps then the colors would transfer over automatically. Also for some reason I'm not seeing the options for color on my filter display.

Comment: @DylanDavis Hmm weird. Are you selecting the column which has cells coloured? I never got this problem before :(

Comment: I figured it out thank you for the help. I sorted them into their colors. I'm trying to copy and paste, but I'm thinking I may be copying too much data from one sheet to the other. The reason I think this is because I am copying the approved rows (green), which is around 26k and when I paste in the approved sheet only 8K appear. Could you guys possibly help me with this situation.

Comment: @DylanDavis Okay, can you say what are the exact steps you are taking (select which row/column up to which row/column, pressing which keys/combinations)? I would also want to know what is your RAM and excel version. Add them into your question so it'll be easier to read please.

Answer (score 0):

Since I guess that you color the cells according to certain condition, than you can copy to other sheet according to this condition.

You can use the filter like suggested above , or sort and then copy.
If you in to code , than you can write some VB script to do that

I think it should something like this (I'm not VBA Expert)

```
Set mrNames = Sheets("MyDataSheet").Range("C2:C100")

For Each cell In mrNames

If cell.Value = "Approved" Then
cell.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Approved").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).PasteSpecial
    End If
```

Comment: I do some coding, but I would consider myself a novice. If there is a VB code for my situation that is simple and easier to understand I am up for anyway to make this task more efficient.

Comment: I figured it out thank you for the help. I sorted them into their colors. I'm trying to copy and paste, but I'm thinking I may be copying too much data from one sheet to the other. The reason I think this is because I am copying the approved rows (green), which is around 26k and when I paste in the approved sheet only 8K appear. Could you guys possibly help me with this situation.